# Trouble drawing Role and Reference grammar trees in latex using rrgtrees package

Tags: pstricks, linguistics, spanish, pst-node, pst-tree

I'm currently trying to draw trees using the rrgtrees package in latex. This package is used to draw syntactical trees for Role and Reference Grammar.

[Here](https://ctan.org/pkg/rrgtrees?lang=en) is the link to the package and the documentation on CTAN

I'm trying to diagram the sentence in Spanish **El médico ya vio varios pacientes** (The doctor already saw various patients)

By compiling the following code on overleaf.com : I'm able to produce the tree that you see below:

```
\documentclass[11pt, spanish]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%Normally I would have used inputenc as overleaf reccomends, but for   some reason when using the packages rrg-trees and their dependencies, I coulnd't get the Spanish accent marks to show up
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{rrgtrees}
% These packages are required
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\psset{treesep=2ex}
 \SENTENCE{
   \CLAUSE{
    \CORE[COREb]{
     \OPR{2}{El}
     \ARG{\WORD(NP){{médico}}}
        \rPERIPH[b]{1}{FA}{\WORD{ya}}
         \NUC{vio}
          \ARG[ACD]{\WORD(NP){varios pacientes}}
      }
     }
    }
\dolinks
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as you can see the PERIPHERY node is blocking the CORE node. That's why I want to try and use \LPERIPH or \RPERIPH because it allows you to set a distance that the PERIPHERY node should be away from the CORE node that it refers to.

For example, when I try the following code:
`

```
\psset{treesep=2ex}
  \SENTENCE{
    \CLAUSE{
      \CORE[COREb]{
        \OPR{2}{El}
        \ARG{\WORD(NP){{médico}}}
            \RPERIPH[b]{5em}{1}{FA}{\WORD{ya}}
        \NUC{vio}
        \ARG[ACD]{\WORD(NP){varios pacientes}}
      }
    }
  }
\dolinks
```

`
I get en error on the \dolinks command that says:

**Missing number, treated as zero.  [ l.50 \dolinks**

If someone could please help me with this error or knows a better way to draw the tree that I'm looking for, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, your snippet does not compile. There is no `\begin{document}` nor `\end{document}`. Could you please make the snippet compilable (and specify how you compile it)?

Comment: Btw and off-topic, there are two different sentences: in the question 
 you use **varios**, but in the code says **varias**. They are way different in Spanish.

Comment: code should be compatible and fixed varios vs. varias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug with `\dolinks`. However, you can set the Periphery individual:

```
\documentclass[11pt, spanish]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{rrgtrees}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\begin{document}

\psset{treesep=2ex}
\SENTENCE{%
  \CLAUSE{%
    \CORE[COREb]{%
      \OPR{2}{El}%
      \ARG{\WORD(NP){médico}}%
      \rPERIPH[b]{1}{\rnode{FA}{FA}}{\WORD{ya}}%
      \NUC{vio}%
      \ARG[ACD]{\WORD(NP){varias pacientes}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\pnode[-3,0](COREb){P0}
\rput(P0){\textsc{Periphery}}
\ncline[nodesepA=1]{->}{P0}{COREb}
\ncangles[armA=0.5,angleA=-90,angleB=90]{P0}{FA}

\end{document}
```

[image]